# Oracle database and .net 3.5 deployment

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have developed an application in C# for .net 3.5. Everything is working fine on my development PC which has "Oracle client developer" installed.

When we are going to install clickonce setup to another PC, it is asking for Oracle data access assembly. What assemblies are required for smooth installation and working?

Regards,

Anil Kumar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ADO.NET data access provider. You should install the provider client library on each client, or adding the library as a copy to include it on the deployment files.

This is a provider for oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the Unmanaged ODP.NET provider you have to copy file `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. For the managed driver the dll is `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`.

Note, the client machine must have an Oracle Client installed. Then you can simply put a copy of mentioned dll's in application .exe directory.